# Find the infimum of the function $2x^3-9x^2+12x+5$ $X\le5$.

Tags: calculus, functions, supremum-and-infimum

> Find the infimum of the function $2x^3-9x^2+12x+5$ $X\le5$.

I think, there the infimum of the $2x^3-9x^2+12x+5$ in the $X\le5$ is -infinity since examining the plot of the function I can see that it goes to $-\infty$. However,I would like to understand if my reasoning is correct and how to find the infimum or supremum of the function more formally in general?

Comment: What are you asking? The title says the set of minimums. That is ambiguous, I thought it referred to the points with zero gradient which are are minima(there is just one at $x=2$). If you mean the infimum why use the plural? Your reasoning for finding the inf of the function you give is fine, What do you mean by "in general"?

Comment: @almagest I am sorry for the ambiguity. The original question that I had in my mind was to show that the set of minimums on the given range is empty and find the infimum. By saying "in general" I seek some reference to theorem or axiom by the usage of which such kind of problems can be solved. This time the function seems to be easy to answer the question. But for example, how should I approach $xsinx$ infimum? If there was a theorem I would like to use it.

Comment: You mean something like this: for a differentiable real-valued function $f(x)$ defined on a finite closed interval $[a,b]$, the minimum value is attained either at an endpoint (ie $a$ or $b$) or at a local minimum $x_0$ (where $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f'$ is negative just before $x_0$ and positive just after it)? In other words, you have to check the endpoints and the local minima to find the minimum value. It should be obvious how to use that for a function defined on an infinite interval.

Comment: @almagest But then I should also show that the minimum of the function if it exists is equal to the infimum. Right? Also, If there is no minimum how can I find the infimum (or it does not exists in this case)?

Comment: For a finite interval the inf and the (global) minimum are the same, because the minimum is **attained**. For an infinite interval, the inf will be equal to the smallest of (1) the smallest local minimum, (2) lim $f(x)$ as $x\to-\infty$ (if that is in the domain), and (3) lim $f(x)$ as $x\to+\infty$ (if that is in the domain). If the domain is not an interval (finite or infinite) then things are slightly more complicated, but the key result you need is the one I gave above.